# contact form in hebrew rtl with phpmailer

Tags: html, right-to-left, hebrew

I have an RTL /Hebrew website. Using PHPMailer / SMTP.

All works fine, including the Contact-Us form, BUT - the email received from that contacct form has all the Hebrew text - LEFT justified, instead of being Right Justified, like any RTL language is.

I have defined in the PHP page : `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';`

The Form page HTML itself is defined as UTF, Hebrew, rtl, textarea is HTML.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing helped and I figured out and fixed it with <p dir="rtl>" and </p> at the end of the body message - like this: <p dir="rtl"> <font style="color:#000000;font-family:arial;font-size:16px"><strong>פרטי ההודעה </strong><br> <br> שם השולח : $Sendername <br> כתבת המייל: $email <br> מספר הטלפון: $Phone <br> <br> $MessageContent</font><font style="color:#000000;font-family:ms shell dlg;font-size:11px"> </font><font style="color:#000000;font-family:arial;font-size:16px"></font> </p>

Answer (score 0):

add `<html dir="rtl" lang="he">`, or even `dir="auto"`.
also `<meta charset="utf-8">` should be added to the `<head>` section.
also see: [Structural markup and right-to-left text in HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir).

Comment: Thanks Martin. I already have the <html dir="rtl" lang="he"> code. I just managed to figure it out by encapsulating the script in between <p dir="rtl"> and </p> and now it looks right. I just have now one other problem. Lines of text in the email body appear as one continous line and ignore the line breaks.... Thanks for your input

Comment: @AlexEvans there also is `bdi`, "bidirectional isolate" markup, see `https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/` ...when there are numbers contained, it might tend to wrap lines, which one has to align.

Comment: Thanks , Nothing helped and I figured out and fixed it with <p dir="rtl>" and </p> at the end of the body message - like this:

<p dir="rtl">
<font style="color:#000000;font-family:arial;font-size:16px"><strong>פרטי ההודעה                               </strong><br>
<br>
 שם השולח :      $Sendername     <br>
כתבת המייל:     $email                 <br>
מספר הטלפון:   $Phone               <br>
<br>
$MessageContent</font><font style="color:#000000;font-family:ms shell dlg;font-size:11px">         </font><font style="color:#000000;font-family:arial;font-size:16px"></font>
</p>

Comment: @AlexEvans numbers inside that `<p dir="rtl"></p>` might need extra wrapping - or `<p dir="bdi"></p>`; balagan, especially with price tags.

Comment: Yes Martin, in my case it is only for Contact form, but it still missbehaves with line breaks and question marks placed in the wrong spot...